# jar file failed to be load "Failed to load class"

Tags: java, exception, dmoz

I am trying to parse a [DMOZ](http://rdf.dmoz.org/rdf/) file, using this [code](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/nutch/trunk/src/java/org/apache/nutch/tools/DmozParser.java). However, after running the code, the application stops at the beginning, producing following exceptions:

```
    SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:146)
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchConfiguration.create(NutchConfiguration.java:59)
    at dmozparser.DmozParser.main(DmozParser.java:375)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

If the jar is set to be `no-operation`, then why they used it in this piece of code? (if that is the case and if it is not the case, then) How to fix this issue?

**EDIT**

according to [this](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder) I added another jar and now there is another exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:146)
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchConfiguration.create(NutchConfiguration.java:59)
    at dmozparser.DmozParser.main(DmozParser.java:339)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more`

**EDIT 2**

Added `commons-logging-1.2.jar` and now it seems there is an `UnsupportedOperationException`:

`Failed to set setXIncludeAware(true) for parser org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@723279cf:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:  setXIncludeAware is not supported on this JAXP implementation or earlier: class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:  setXIncludeAware is not supported on this JAXP implementation or earlier: class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setXIncludeAware(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:584)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:1131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:1107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:1053)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:420)
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchConfiguration.setUUID(NutchConfiguration.java:41)
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchConfiguration.create(NutchConfiguration.java:60)
    at dmozparser.DmozParser.main(DmozParser.java:339)`

This seems that `org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl` is not supported but how to replace it with an appropriate one?

Comment: How are you running this code?  Is it part of a Maven project, are you using the command line, or are you trying to run it directly from your IDE?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please take a look at my EDITs. and yes, I am trying to run it directly from IDE (netbeans) through a Java application.